# Angular V5 with Django rest framework url not laoding

Tags: django, angular-ui-router

I am working on Angular5 with Django rest framework.

I am trying to integrate the Django url with angular5. it is working only for index page. and if we change the state by clicking on any Button its working good but on page load it showing "**Page not found (404)**".

The url for index page is:

```
url(r'^$',TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html"),name="index")
```

Before load :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7qF1.png)

After Load page:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m086B.png)

Cab anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to have the button click reload the page and bring you to the contact page? If so, you're getting the 404 error because your app is trying to access /contactus which doesn't exist within your URL patterns. If you want that URL to return anything other than a 404, you'll need to put an entry for it into urls.py

Right below the line you have for urls.py you can put

```
...
url(r'^$',TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html"),name="index"),
url(r'^contactus', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='contactus.html'), name='contactus'),
...
```

Then make a template for contactus.html

If you want the text of /contactus to be loaded into the page without a refresh, you can return the HTML that you'd like inserted into the document by changing the contactus view to return a JSON response.

```
class ContactUsView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        contact_html = render(request, 'contactus.html', {})
        return JsonResponse({'contact_html': contact_html})
```

Either way, the reason behind the 404 is that you haven't told django what data you'd like to return from the /contactus endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the solution I used **{ useHash: true }** in app.routing.ts that allowed the '#' in url and it is working fine.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true }) ],
    exports : [RouterModule]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**I found two Solutions for the same**

#### 1. The Django Way

In this method you do following

1. Create one url for rendering your application and another url for handling other pages routed by angular.

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='home'), // Renders index page

url(r'^(?P<path>.*)/$', views.index), //handles other pages using django query params
```

**view.py**

```
def index(request, path=''):
    """
    Renders homepage and handles other pages
    """
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

So what this method does is for index page it simply renders the index.html and if page is reloaded a request is sent to django and django simply loads the index.html again with your current routes preserved but loading index.html means loading whole application because angular is single page application and loading complete page is a disadvantage

#### 2. The Angular Way

This method simply uses Hash Location strategy for routing, the routing is done using hash

**app.modules.ts (or app.routing.module.ts)**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    //Other Modules
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
  ],
```

so it'll render django url like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/#/home`

This solution is the best example where you can handle page not found 404 on page refresh condition in django-angular(v7) app, using django query params or hash location strategy

Django Way [Reference](https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/url-routing-decoupled-app-angular-2-and-django)
Angular way [Reference 2](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/routing-strategies/)